# Bootstrap File Input in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I want to use a good file input of Bootstrap and tried [Bootstrap File Input](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/) as given on the examples on that page. However, I am looking for a multiple file uploading and a style as shown below but there is not such a kind of example on any pages of the web. How can I create a file upload as shown below? And is there a better file input of Bootstrap than [Bootstrap File Input](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput)?

[image]

Comment: Has anybody else use **Bootstrap File Upload**???

Answer (score 1):

try "Bootstrap Drag and Drop Upload" by Bootsnipp.
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-drag-and-drop-upload

or dropzonejs file upload

http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, but these example of Bootstrap does not seem to that one I posted above. Any other example of Bootstrap File Upload? Voted+